# Streaming lines of text from file with IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, system.io.file, c#-8.0, iasyncenumerable

I came across IAsyncEnumerable while I am testing C# 8.0 features. I found remarkable examples from  Anthony Chu (https://anthonychu.ca/post/async-streams-dotnet-core-3-iasyncenumerable/). It is async stream and replacement for `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`

```
// Data Access Layer.
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    Container container = cosmosClient.GetContainer(DatabaseId, ContainerId);
    var iterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Product>("SELECT * FROM c");
    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        foreach (var product in await iterator.ReadNextAsync())
        {
            yield return product;
        }
    }
}

// Usage
await foreach (var product in productsRepository.GetAllProducts())
{
    Console.WriteLine(product);
}
```

I am wondering if this can be applied to read text files like below usage that read file line by line.

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Filename"))
{
    // ...process line.
}
```

I really want to know how to apply async with `IAsyncEnumerable<string>()` to the above foreach loop so that it streams while reading.

How do I implement iterator so that I can use yield return to read line by line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly the same, however there is no async workload, so let's pretend

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> SomeSortOfAwesomeness()
{
   foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Filename.txt"))
   {
       // simulates an async workload, 
       // otherwise why would be using IAsyncEnumerable?
       // -- added due to popular demand 
       await Task.Delay(100);
       yield return line;
   }
}
```

or

This is just an wrapped APM workload, see [Stephen Clearys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) comments for clarification

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> SomeSortOfAwesomeness()
{
   using StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("Filename.txt");
   while(!reader.EndOfStream)
      yield return await reader.ReadLineAsync();
}
```

**Usage**

```
await foreach(var line in SomeSortOfAwesomeness())
{
   Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

**Update** from [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)

> `File.OpenText` sadly only allows *synchronous I/O*; the *async APIs* are
>   implemented poorly in that scenario. To open a true *asynchronous file*,
>   you'd need to use a `FileStream` constructor passing `isAsync`: true or
>   `FileOptions.Asynchronous`.

`ReadLineAsync` basically results in this code, as you can see, it's only the Stream APM `Begin` and `End` methods wrapped

```
private Task<Int32> BeginEndReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
{            
     return TaskFactory<Int32>.FromAsyncTrim(
                    this, new ReadWriteParameters { Buffer = buffer, Offset = offset, Count = count },
                    (stream, args, callback, state) => stream.BeginRead(args.Buffer, args.Offset, args.Count, callback, state), // cached by compiler
                    (stream, asyncResult) => stream.EndRead(asyncResult)); // cached by compiler
}
```

Comment: what!!! Mind Blown. I was thinking about some kind of hack to be truly async. So microsoft not intend to put more async method in IO operation.

Comment: Can I say second method is near async than first method? My objective is to subscribe to this stream and try some reactive stuffs.

Comment: @phonemyatt the first one has no need to be `IAsyncEnumerable` without the `Task.Delay`. the second actually uses *async* methods of the `StreamReader` class which wraps the reading of *AMP* methods with minimal overhead

Comment: `File.OpenText` sadly only allows synchronous I/O; the async APIs are implemented poorly in that scenario. To open a true asynchronous file, you'd need to use a `FileStream` constructor passing `isAsync: true` or `FileOptions.Asynchronous`.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks for the clarification, ill update

Comment: @TheodorZoulias in this example, none whats so ever. just simulating an async workload. afterall, if its not async then it might as well be a standard IEnumerble

Comment: Ahh, I see. You could add a commend at the end of this line, like `// simulates an async workload`, to make it obvious that this code is not intended to be used as is.

Answer (score 3):

I did some performance tests and it seems that a large `bufferSize` is helpful, together with the [`FileOptions.SequentialScan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileoptions) option.

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<string> ReadLinesAsync(string filePath)
{
    using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
        FileShare.Read, 32768, FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan);
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    while (true)
    {
        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (line == null) break;
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

The enumeration in not trully asynchronous though. According to my experiments (.NET Core 3.1) the `xxxAsync` methods of the `StreamReader` class are blocking the current thread for a duration longer than the awaiting period of the `Task` they return. For example reading a 6 MB file with the method [`ReadToEndAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync) in my PC blocks the current thread for 120 msec before returning the task, and then the task is completed in just 20 msec. So I am not sure that there is much value at using these methods. Faking asynchrony is much easier by using the synchronous APIs together with some [Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/):

```
IAsyncEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines("SomeFile.txt").ToAsyncEnumerable();
```

---

**.NET 6 update:** The implementation of the asynchronous filesystem APIs has been improved on .NET 6. For experimental data with the `File.ReadAllLinesAsync` method, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217657/why-file-readalllinesasync-blocks-the-ui-thread/63218926#63218926).